# Parsing an XML file into linked java objects

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm using a SAX parser on an XML file to create objects that reference one another.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"> 
 <course number="CSC212">
  <textbook name="BookFor212"/> 
 </course> 
 <course number="CSC241"> 
  <prereq number="CSC212"/>
  <textbook name="BookFor241"/> 
  <textbook name="AnotherBookFor241"/> 
 </course> 
 <course number="CSC455"> 
  <prereq number="CSC241"/> 
  <prereq number="CSC365"/> 
  <textbook name="BookFor455"/> 
 </course> 
 <course number="CSC365"> 
  <prereq number="CSC241"/> 
  <textbook name="BookFor365"/> 
  <textbook name="AnotherBookFor365"/> 
  <textbook name="YetAnotherBookFor365"/> 
 </course> 
</xml>
```

So I create a course and add the textbooks and prereqs to the respective arrays within the course and to finish I add that course to an array. After parsing, the user is then prompted to enter a course number and the program spits out the info, including the prereqs and everything they entail, so their textbooks and prereqs as well.

```
public class Course {
private String number;
private Course[] prereqs = new Course[5];
private int pCounter = 0;
private Textbook[] books = new Textbook[5];
private int tCounter = 0;

public Course(String n) {
  number = n;
}

public String getNumber() {
  return number;
}

public void addPrereq(Course prereq) {
  prereqs[pCounter++] = prereq;
}

public void addTextbook(Textbook book) {
  books[tCounter++] = book;
}

public String toString() {
  String retVal = "Course: " + number + (tCounter == 0 ? ", No books." : ", textbooks:   ");
  for (int i = 0; i < tCounter; i++)
    retVal += books[i].toString() + " ";
  retVal += "\n" + (pCounter == 0 ? "No prerequisites.\n" : "Prerequisites:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < pCounter; i++)
    retVal += prereqs[i].toString();
  return retVal + "End of course " + number + ".\n";
}
}
```

The problem is when adding the prereqs I look through the array of already created courses and use it if it's there and create a new one if it's not. So if it's not there, I add a course that doesn't have any info besides its number. So I end up with course CSC455 having a prereq CSC365 but no textbooks or prereqs are listed. How can I do this so that the prereqs are the finished course?

Comment: You need to do a two pass parse; store the `String` prereq on the course then create a `Map<String, Course>` and have some sort of method on the course `resolvePrereq(final Map<String, Course> lookupMap)` that you loop over and call afterwards.

Comment: If you add the source for your `Course` it would be easier to be specific as to a solution.

Comment: That's what I thought of doing but I'm not really sure how.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a `Map` to lookup your courses.  Whenever your come across a new `Course` or a reference you check the map and then put new `Course`s into the map. This way you can create a `Course` from a req then add the information later.

I would suggest using `List`s or `Set`s in your `Course` as this would mean that your won't get an `ArrayOutOfBounds` when you have more than 5 textbooks.

```
public class Course {

    private String number;
    private List<Course> prereqs = new LinkedList<Course>();
    private List<Textbook> books = new LinkedList<Textbook>();

    public Course(String n) {
        number = n;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void addPrereq(Course prereq) {
        prereqs.add(prereq);
    }

    public void addTextbook(Textbook book) {
        books.add(book);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String retVal = "Course: " + number + (books.isEmpty() ? ", No books." : ", textbooks:   ");
        for (final Textbook  book : books) {
            retVal += book.toString() + " ";
        }
        retVal += "\n" + (prereqs.isEmpty() ? "No prerequisites.\n" : "Prerequisites:\n");
        for (final Course course : prereqs) {
            retVal += course.toString();
        }
        return retVal + "End of course " + number + ".\n";
    }
}
```

Now you need to store a `Map<String, Course>` and add a `getCourse()` method that you use rather than constructing new courses - this is a factory pattern:

```
private class CourseFactory {

    private final Map<String, Course> courseMap;

    public CourseFactory(final Map<String, Course> courseMap) {
        this.courseMap = courseMap;
    }

    public Course getCourse(final String name) {
        Course course = courseMap.get(name);
        if(course == null) {
            course = new Course(name);
            courseMap.put(name, course);
        }
        return course;
    }
}
```

So now at the top of your parser you create a `CourseFactory` and use that to get your courses. It will deal with making sure you always reference the same one.